# Unable to share aliases across steps in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am having an issue trying to share an alias between two steps in cypress. Basically what I am trying to do is in the first then step, I get the value and pass it in as a variable `storedOddsValue`. In the second then step, when I try to get that alias value and complete the step, it fails because I beleive it's coming back with undefined.

I know this because instead of using:

```js
let storedOddsValue = oddslib.from("fractional", cy.get("@storedOddsValue"));
```

If I replace the alias with the hardcoded value like so:

```
let storedOddsValue = oddslib.from("fractional", "13/5");
```

The whole code below executes fine and the assertion passes. So my question is what am I doing wrong, why is it not getting the alias?

```
Then ("The prices are formatted in fractions by default", () => {
    priceFormatElements.priceFormatDropdown().should('have.value', 'Fraction');
    const oddsValue = oddsSelectionElements.oddsButton().first().invoke("text");

    oddsValue.then((oddsValue) => {
        expect(oddsValue.trim()).contains("/");
        oddsValue.trim();
    }).as("storedOddsValue")
})

Then ("The prices are formatted in {string}", (priceFormat) => {
    let expectedOddsValue;
    let currentOddsValue = oddsSelectionElements.oddsButton().first().invoke("text");
    //let storedOddsValue = oddslib.from("fractional", "13/5");
    let storedOddsValue = oddslib.from("fractional", cy.get("@storedOddsValue"));
    
    switch (priceFormat) {
        case "Fractional":
          expectedOddsValue = storedOddsValue.to("fractional");
          break;
        case "Decimal":
          expectedOddsValue = storedOddsValue.to("decimal", {precision: 2});
          break;
        case "American":
          expectedOddsValue = "+" + storedOddsValue.to("moneyline");  
          break;
        default:
          throw new Error('unknown price format: ' + priceFormat);
    }
    
    currentOddsValue.then((oddsValue) => {
        expect(oddsValue.trim()).equals(expectedOddsValue);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what `oddslib.from` does, but to use it with an alias you need to nest in this way

```js
Then (... () => {
  let expectedOddsValue
  let currentOddsValue = oddsSelectionElements.oddsButton().first().invoke("text")

  cy.get("@storedOddsValue").then(aliasValue => {

    let storedOddsValue = oddslib.from("fractional", aliasValue)

    switch (priceFormat) {
      ...
    }
    currentOddsValue.then((oddsValue) => {
      expect(oddsValue.trim()).equals(expectedOddsValue);
    });

  })   // end of cy.get("@storedOddsValue")
})
```

Because `cy.get("@storedOddsValue")` is asynchronous, and the `switch()` runs before it gives it's value.